# Find all consecutive sum of subset in O(n^2) using dp

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Question :

Given n numbers ,,…,, consider the problem of computing [,]=++⋯, for all <=. A naive algorithm by computing each [,] independently will take (^) time. Derive an efficient way to solve this problem in (^) time.

I tried to draw a 2-dimension table which row and column are both 1~n, and find some formula to fill all table(upper triangle). But I think each block is irregular, maybe this is not good idea. Are there any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your idea to use a 2-dimenstion table (only the upper triangle) is correct.
Then, you only need to notice that:

[image]

and that

[image]

Each input of your table will hence be computed in O(1), and the whole upper triangle in O(n^2)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for O(n^2) memory though. You can use what is called prefix sums. Create an array 'prefsum[n]', where for each i in (1 ... n) prefsum[i] = x1 + x2 + ... + xi. If you want to get sum in range (l, r), just take prefsum[r] - prefsum[l - 1] (obviously if l-1 > 0, otherwise your result is prefsum[r]). This way you can calculate prefsum in O(n) (simple for loop) and get result for any range in O(1). Since there are O(n^2) different ranges, your complexity is O(n^2).